# How to fire a keyboard shortcut through a button in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a project in Angular which has a event slideshow. I want that when I click on the button to start the slideshow, it should become full screen (Windows - fn+F11).

How can I fire a keyboard shortcut function in Angular?

Thanks.

Comment: I actually got my solution from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242775/angular-7-how-does-work-the-html5-fullscreen-api-ive-a-lot-of-errors

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make the slideshow fullscreen, then consider using [screenfull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull). It's a javascript library to help you achieve your goal. You will need to pass the element that you want to be fullscreen. In your case, it is your slideshow.

```
import * as screenfull from 'screenfull';    

slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow')

startSlideshow() { 
  screenfull.request(this.slideshow)
}
```

Comment: @Mr.A no problem;)